# Computing the singular homology group of a mapping torus with an expanding map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

One can think $2$-dimensional torus as

$$[0,1]\times S^1/(0,x)\sim~(1,x),$$

and the Klein's bottle as

$$[0,1]\times S^1/(0,x)\sim(1,1-x).$$

I want to ask that if one constructs a special kind of torus with an expanding map by

$$[0,1]\times S^1/(0,x)\sim(1,2x \text{ mod } 1),$$

what is the singular homology group of this space?

Comment: What you've described seems more like cylinders and Mobius bands, rather than tori and Klein bottles.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! i will edit it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cellular homology: your space has the structure of a CW complex with one $0$-cell, two 1-cells (denoted $a$ and $b$) and one $2$-cell.  Graphically, you have a fundamental pentagon with boundary word $a^2 b a^{-1} b^{-1}$.  From this you can read off the cellular boundary maps.  The map $C_1 \to C_0$ is $0$ since each edge starts and ends at the same point.  The map $C_2 \cong \mathbb{Z} \to C_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ takes the generator to $2a + b - a - b = a$.  From this you can easily compute the homology.  If I did everything correctly, I get $H_0 = \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ (generated by $b$) and $H_i = 0$ for $i \geq 2$.

Comment: First, Thank you for the nice answer! I want to ask you one more thing.  From the fact that 2nd homology group is 0, is the space non-orientable?

Comment: It is not a manifold...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Do you mean that the space can not be a manifold?

Comment: I mean precisely what I wrote: that it is not a manifold.

Comment: To add to Mariano's answer, if you don't already see it: near the vertical edges with the "expanding map" gluing, you have three planes meeting at an edge.  So it's not a manifold.